# Calculating Pay-back Period

Tags: sql, postgresql, e-commerce

I'd like to calculate the time it takes for a customer to reach their "pay-back-period". That is, when they effectively have spent enough money with our store to offset the advertising cost for that specific customer.

```
Customers
| id | created_at | acquisition_cost |
| 3 | 2019-03-04 20:24:49 | 39.90 |

Orders
| id | customer_id | created_at | profit |
| 39 | 3 | 2019-04-03 05:39:39 | 19.91 |
| 86 | 3 | 2019-06-03 07:29:18 | 17.39 |
```

What I want to know is if there's a performant way in Postgresql to find the `created_at` of the order (ordered by `created_at ASC`) that puts the customer over the 39.90 `acquisition_cost`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cumulative sums:

```
select c.*,
       sum(o.profit) over (partition by o.customer_id order by o.created_at) as running-profit
from orders o join
     customers c
     on o.customer_id = c.id;
```

If you want the first date, then:

```
select distinct on (id) oc.*
from (select c.*, o.created_at as order_created_at,
             sum(o.profit) over (partition by o.customer_id order by o.created_at) as running_profit
      from orders o join
           customers c
           on o.customer_id = c.id
     ) oc
where running_profit >= c.acquisition_cost
order by id, order_created_at
```